# How to override a Magestore extension's layout file?

Tags: magento2, extensions

I am trying to override

**/var/www/Company/app/code/Magestore/Megamenu/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

I have tried:

**/var/www/Company/app/design/frontend/Business/business-theme/Magestore_Megamenu/layout/default.xml** but no luck.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same way you override core themes,

```
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/MyTheme/Vendor_Module/layout/some_layout_xml.xml
```

Remember clear cache and set developer mode, or deploy static content via bin.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```